# for loop through fetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I need to loop through a fetchedResultsController but having some issues.  Here is the code;

```
for (NSFetchedResultsController *singleResult in _fetchedResultsController) {
    //For logic
}
```

The warning is;

```
Collection expression type 'NSFetchedResultsController *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need a loop? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

You need to access a member of the `_fetchedResultsController` that is an iterateable type, such as `NSArray` or `NSSet`.  For example, `NSFetchedResultsController` has a property called `fetchedObjects` that is an `NSArray`.  I suspect this is the array you are looking to access.  I am not terribly familiar with the `NSFetchedResultsController`, but [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a link to the class reference that should help you out the rest of the way

Comment: aka `for (NSManagedObject *result in _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects)`